# Need help in access query

Tags: sql, ms-access, excel-2007, ms-access-2007

I have doubt in access query...

Pls advise is it possible

i have linked the excel file into access,its has some number of columns ..My ques is

for E.g

To retrieve the description and Region column from laptop,Desktop table

i do use below query

```
SELECT Laptop.[Description], Laptop.[Region] From Laptop 
union SELECT Desktop.[Description], Desktop.[Region] From Desktop
```

sometimes ..It may not contain Region field, in that time I do use “ ” as Laptop.[Region] or "" as Desktop.[Region]

My quest is

Is there any option like this

```
SELECT Laptop.[Description], If Laptop.[Region]=avairable 
     then Laptop.[Region] else “” as [Region] from Laptop;
```

or any way to skip from error...

Please help me in this ...THx in advance

Doubt:

To be clear

If desktop table has description and region Column ..

```
Description Region
Saran       east
Sathish     north 
sathy       west
```

And

Laptop has Desktop table has description and Cost …

```
Description  Cost
asdf         23
dkasfjasd    34
flkasdf      55
```

```
Select Laptop.[Description], NZ(Laptop.[Region], "NA") as [Region] 
from Laptop 
UNION 
SELECT Desktop.[Description], NZ(Desktop.[Region], "NA") as [Region] 
FROM Desktop;
```

Will it return this result ?

I can’t run this because I had some access issue

```
Description  Region
asdf              
dkasfjasd   
flkasdf 
Saran        east
Sathish      north 
sathy        west
```

Comment: Yes correct its Must be FROM Desktop.. i have corrected that.. Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use switch case for this query but in mS-acess its not supported but the other way out of doing it in access is use of iif() here I am giving you a generic example you can easily convert this in your actual query.

```
IIf(expr, truepart, falsepart)

 SELECT  IIF(IsNull(Laptop.[Region])," ",Laptop.[Region]) as region
FROM Laptop ;
```

Comment: Access SQL does indeed have a `SWITCH()` function e.g. `SELECT SWITCH([Region] IS NOT NULL, [Region], TRUE, '{{NO REGION}}') FROM Laptop;`

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you ment in your pseudo-code that '=avairable' means a value exists. You just want to handle a null value.

```
Select Laptop.Description, NZ(Laptop.Region, "") as [Region] from Laptop;
```

The [NZ() function](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/nz-function-HA001228890.aspx) will handle the null values and substitute whatever you want.

Comment: @MattDonnan - good point. Especially if you want to check for values other than null or need something more complex.

Comment: Can pls clarify my quest .. i have added that ques in my question (Doubt:)